# Not able to generate signed apk while i can crate debug apk and can generate app bundle alss

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I am able to install as debug apk also able to generate signed app bundle but when i try to generate signed release apk getting this error

## /Users/raka/.gradle/caches/transforms-      3/b4c27f2043c4bd894619966c2413f31b/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-  18.1.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-  INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.common_logger.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

```
I got few suggestions that try to change recaptcha library version but i can't get recaptcha    library in my build.gradle.
I also try to solve this CHATGPT and Bard but did not getting any right answer
```

Comment: post your gradle file